# How to set a build on TFS and automatically upload project to server

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-sdk

Is there any possibility to set behavior on TFS that will build a project and automatically upload it to test server?

Comment: Is this a web or windows project?

Comment: That's the kind of thing ["make"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742325/how-to-build-a-vs2010-makefile-project-vcxproj-with-tfs-build-no-vs-2010) files excel at :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `paulsm4` posted in comment.

> The Microsoft answer is "script MSBuild".

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool like cruisecontrol.net to automate this for you. Lots of reading here, but bottom line, yes it is possible.

http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/documents

> The server application, which is the automated integration server, is the core of the CruiseControl.NET project.
>   The Server automates the integration process by monitoring the team's source control repository directly. Every time a developer commits a new set of modifications, the server will automatically launch an integration build to validate the changes. When the build is complete, the server notifies the developer whether the changes that they committed integrated successfully or not.
>   Effectively, integration becomes as easy as checking in code. Using an automated integration server not only makes integration easy, it also guarantees that an integration build will happen. There is no danger of developers forgetting to validate their changes after checking in.
>   The CCNet Server offers several key features:
>   Integration with a variety of Source Control systems (vss, csv, svn, git, hg, alienbrain, bitkeeper, perforce, clearcase, filesystem, ftp, ...)
>   Integration with other external tools, such as NAnt, Msbuild, NDepend, Nunit, MBUnit, Watin, Visual Studio, ....
>   Can build multiple projects on one server
>   Remote management
>   Reporting : email, launch exe, rss, ...

Comment: The Microsoft answer is "script MSBuild".  Personally, think that answer sucks :(  +1: CruiseControl.net is an excellent suggestion.  IMHO...