# Meteorite installation error on windows XP - "c:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found

Tags: c++, node.js, meteor, npm, router

I'm learning to create meteor application on my windows machine now. Everything is working fine because http://win.meteor.com have windows installation that I can try with.
The problem I have is now I want to have routing capability in my app. From my research the Meteor-Router package can add by using meteorite. So here's what I've done

1. Install node.js for windows --> everything looks OK, I can type node -v to look at node version
2. Install meteorite by type `npm install -g meteorite` --> every working fine up until async module installation that complain about "c:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found

   I've try googling to looking for the answer but have no luck.
   Any idea for me to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742325/how-to-build-a-vs2010-makefile-project-vcxproj-with-tfs-build-no-vs-2010) may be a duplicate. it was the *first* hit when i selected your text and googled it.

Comment: Dear Alf, thank you for your advice. If I'm not wrong I used to try to install SDK last time but it still fail (I select option per this picture http://i.minus.com/jAIzaHuWsXD9e.jpg). But I'll try one more time.
 btw, how do I accept your answer?

Answer (score -1):

[According to meteorite's official documentation](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite#installing-meteorite), Meteorite does not work in Windows as of time of writing this. Sorry.

> ... However, meteorite's git based approach runs counter to the MSI installation that's required to get it working. So meteorite does not work under windows right now. Pull Requests which change this would be gladly accepted!